# Is there a better way for my CNN to handle random values?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, autoencoders, contrastive-learning

I made an autoencoder to, ideally, turn an image into seemingly random numbers(Using a loss that determines randomness) and turn those random numbers into the original image. The results were kind of meh. The ideal encoded image would just look like rainbow static, but I got this instead:

[image: Badly Encoded Image]

The decoded image was also kind of bad, but that's the same problem as the encoder. I was wondering if there was a better way to handle the image -> random -> image conversions better. Like maybe changing the stride length or filter size could help it learn global features better. Here is what my current encoder and decoder look like:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
x = Conv2D(4, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', groups=1)(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

Pls don't judge my autoencoder    Thanks

Comment: Why should you be able to reconstruct the image from random values?

Comment: @Dave The encoded images wouldn't really be random, but I have a loss on the encoder based on how random the distribution of images is. This way, it can create a random-looking image for each real image while being able to sneak information through to the decoder. I just have a problem where CNNs are good at spatially related images, but not random numbers.

Comment: That last part makes it sound like the CNN is doing what it’s supposed to do. It isn’t supposed to invent patterns out of randomness (that’s overfitting, at least a little loosely speaking).

Comment: @NathanaelSuarez To receive an answer quickly, it may help to clearly outline your question in the post.